# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'

Tags: software-installation, python3, virtualenv

I'm new to Ubuntu (20.04.2.0 LTS) and trying to get Python3.9.6 and Pip to work with Virtualenv.

I hope some of you experienced Ubuntu users can help me :)

I have no problem using default Python (3.8.10):

```
$ python3 -V Python 3.8.10

$ whereis python3 
/usr/bin/python3.8

$ pip3 -V 
pip 21.1.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ virtualenv env_python3.8 
created virtual environment CPython3.8.10.final.0-64 in 155ms

$ source env_python3.8/bin/activate

(env_python3.8) usagi@dev:~$ pip list 
Package Version
pip 20.0.2 pkg-resources 0.0.0
setuptools 44.0.0 wheel 0.34.2

(env_python3.8) usagi@dev:~$ pip install django 
Successfully installed asgiref-3.4.1 django-3.2.5 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1

(env_python3.8) usagi@dev:~$ pip list 
Package Version
asgiref 3.4.1
Django 3.2.5
pip 20.0.2 pkg-resources 0.0.0
pytz 2021.1 setuptools 44.0.0 sqlparse 0.4.1
wheel 0.34.2
```

These steps work without any problems, but if I do the same steps for Python3.9.6 (from source), it will not work:

```
$ python3.9 -V 
Python 3.9.6

$ whereis python3 
/usr/local/bin/python3.9

Guess this is one the problems, pip3 looking at Python3.8
$ pip3 -V 
pip 21.1.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.9 env_python3.9 
created virtual environment CPython3.9.6.final.0-64 in 113ms

$ source env_python3.9/bin/activate

(env_python3.9) usagi@dev:~$ python -V 
Python 3.9.6

(env_python3.9) usagi@dev:~$ pip -V 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/usagi
/env_python3.9/bin/pip", line 5, in from pip._internal.cli.main import main File "/home
/usagi/env_python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in 
from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete File "/home/usagi/env_python3.9
/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in from 
pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser File "/home/usagi/env_python3.9
/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in from 
pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions File "/home/usagi/env_python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in from pip._internal.exceptions 
import CommandError File "/home/usagi/env_python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 10, in from pip._vendor.six import iteritems 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'
```

Tried to find information about the error but could not find a solution.

If any of you have had the same problem or recognize the problem and would like to help me, I am grateful for all the help I can get.

Best regards, /Mikael

Comment: What does `python3.9 -m pip --version` return?

Comment: Hello @ajgringo619,
Thanks for the answer!
The command returns:

$ python3.9 -m pip --version
/usr/local/bin/python3.9: No module named pip.

There we probably have the problem.

Next question: how do I install pip to /usr/local/bin/python3.9.

Comment: How did you install python3.9?

Comment: Hello again!

I have installed Python3.9.6 from source.

Comment: Tried installing it with sudo apt install Python 3.9 and it worked with virtualenv and pip. The problem then is that I can't choose exactly which Python version to install.

Comment: If you decide to stick with the compiled version, just rebuild it with `--with-ensurepip=install` added to your `configure` command. I would not keep both versions.

Comment: I reinstall my computer with Ubuntu. Installed Python with --with-ensurepip = install. Created a virtual environment with Virtualenv. Everything works fine until I use Pip and get the same error message again: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'`. Do you have any other idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't tell you why your compiled version is not working. Using the Ubuntu repo, you can get what you want and will get updated with the rest of the system:

```
sudo apt install python3.9 python3.9-venv
```

this will give you `pip3.9` and the ability to create a virtual environment, something like this:

```
python3.9 -m venv $HOME/.venv/python3.9
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! Now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'` errors when running Django app on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with pipenv. Solution was to remove some old virtualenv version files with `rm -rf ~/.local/share/virtualenvs` after which package installations started working and I was able to run the app. Might be worth a try.

Gave a more verbose answer on this to another SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542588/1669514, but thought to drop it also here as both came high on my searches while spending half a day figuring it out.